# Rename [android-externalstorage] to [android-external-storage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Rename [android-externalstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-externalstorage) to [android-external-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-external-storage)

This is possibly a typo since we have a [android-internal-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-internal-storage).

Comment: I renamed the tag ... blame my OCD, but we need some sort of consistency in naming the tags, else the gods of good patterns will look down and laugh at us.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not so worried about them laughing, I'm worried about them cringing at our patternless imperfection and squashing us like hideous bugs. For the sake of the Stack Overflow Community's survival, we need some consistency ;D